# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tracker.get')

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have code straight from the google analytics docs. For some reason get an error, only sometimes `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tracker.get')`
what does this mean? and what is the difference between this type of error and an error that says `property 'get' does not exist on undefined` ?

```
private hasDefaultTracker(): boolean {    
 var clientId;
    window.ga(function(tracker) {
        clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
    });
    return clientId != null;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is straight from the google analytics code? Can you provide a reference to the relevant document?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the Google analytics client ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053949/how-to-get-the-google-analytics-client-id)

Comment: This look like standard, [how to return from asynchronous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Comment: Maybe you can find answer here: [trackingid-and-clientid-with-google-tag-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189563/trackingid-and-clientid-with-google-tag-manager)

Comment: from the docs 
`ga(function(tracker) {
  // Logs the client ID for the current user.
  console.log(tracker.get('clientId'));
});`

Comment: @jcubic can you elaborate?

Comment: `ga(function(tracker) {` is async function you can't assign the value that's inside  and check outside, the value is only inside the function, because it runs after the check. it's like `setTimeout`.

Comment: also your code need to be inside of the function, otherwise it will be syntax error. You can't have return at top level.

Comment: @jcubic while debugging, the `clientId = tracker.get('clientId');` line is called before the return

Comment: Maybe you proved wrong data when you initialized GA.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, inside my callback function i'm getting the tracker as undefined, any idea how to solve it?